# Simulink Index out of bound - False error?

Tags: matlab, indexoutofboundsexception, simulink

on simulink, I have this error :

```
Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1
```

for this line of code in an embedded function, Simulink cannot access `Point1(2)` or `Point2(2)`:

```
midPoint= [(Point1(1) + Point2(1))/2,(Point1(2) + Point2(2))/2 ];
```

This is the only line of code where I call `Point1` and `Point2`. However it seems that the block inputs has the right bounds:

[image: Simulink block inputs bound size img]

Do you have an idea where this can come from? Thank you for your time.

Following Phil answer, 
I am sorry but I can't give you the full code.
However, I can give the bit of code used to create the two points in the previous block function. I hope it can be useful

```
[A,B,Point1,Point2,C]  = fcn(transition,...)

Point1 =[0,0];
Point2 =[0,0];

  if transition == 1
    if condition1 < k1 
      Point1 =[x11, y11];    
    else
      Point1 =[x12, y12];
    end

    if condition2 < k2 
      Point2 =[x21, y21];
    else
      Point2 =[x22, y22];
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Show us your whole code.

Comment: Hello Phil, thank you for your answer, you must have received a lot of notifications due to my lack of editing skill, sorry for that. 
I edited the question.

Comment: That code doesn't help.  You need to show us the code where the error is occurring, not how the data is created.

Comment: I may have misled you, the error is occuring during the compilation of simulink before running. (I therefore cannot debug it while the simulation runs so I do not have much information to troobleshoot the error) The error is from the diagnostic panel and occuring at the line of code describind midpoint which is the only line I call Point1 and Point2.

Comment: I found the answer, instead of calling the point like that:  `Point1(2)` I called it like that:  `Point1(1,2)`. Moreover I rebooted the PC and erased the .mex file, it may have helped. (is it possible that the .mex file was erroned ... ? )

Comment: Which is a reason why we needed to see the actual code. Nonetheless, glad to hear you sorted out the problem.